# how to solve systems of linear inequalities with parameters on python?

Tags: python, sympy

So here my inequalities :

```
alpha * y >= x + y  
beta * x >= x + y  
x > 0  
y > 0
```

and I would like to have a Coordinate system (alpha, beta) with (alpha, beta) green when alpha beta meet the conditions and red when it's not the case.

Someone know how to do that on python ?

thank you

Comment: What does "when it's ok" mean?

Answer (score 0):

In Python, we use Eq () method to create an equation from the expression. Syntax : Eq (expression,RHS value) For example, if we have expression as x+y = 1. It can be written as Eq (x+y,1) Solving equation with two variables Construct the equations using Eq () method. To solve the equations pass them as a parameter to the solve () function

Comment: Need better formatting